# Find files with lines changed in the specified commits

Tags: git

How can I find files that have changed from the specified commits?  There are file that changed with those commits and still have those changes in HEAD.  So, if I change a line in one commit, then change the same line in another commit, that line will not be included in the search result.

For example there are files `f1`, `f2` and commits `c1`, `c2`.

commit `c1` introduces some changes to `f1` and `f2`

commit `c2` changes `f1` in such way that there are no more changes from `c1` left (it changes at least every line that was changed in `c1`). Also it changes `f2` in the way that preserves some changes from `c1` (at least one line changed in `c1` is not changed).

Search should return file `f2` as it contains changed from `c1` which is searched. However search should not return `f1` as all changes there are overwritten by `c2`.

Comment: can you add the commands you're trying to use?

Comment: Don't understand the queston. Provide examples.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to know which files are different between two commits? Use `git diff` to compare two tree-ish objects:

```
git diff --name-only commit1 commit2
```

Comment: not different, I want to find all files that contain lines changed in the specified commits in the HEAD. So as I described in the question if changes are overwritten by another commit then they are not included in the final result. In other words using blame on found file should show at least one line changed in at least one of the specified commits.

Comment: @mishanesterenko If that's what you want, what's wrong with using `git blame` and `grep` to get your answer?

Comment: @mishanesterenko: have you actually tried diff? I cannot help, but think that it does what you want, i.e. »not show changes that were overwritten/changed back«